# How would I change a value inserted into a database to a variable I have created from JavaScript/ajax?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I've created a route planner where users travel to work and gain points based on the type of transport they use, I want to then store the points they earn cumulatively in a database I have created, but I am having a problem with using the JavaScript variable from the Route Planner so that it is inserted into the database, as I do not know the right SQL statement to use.

I've changed the SQL statements from 'INSERT INTO' to 'UPDATE' by changing the field in the database host I use and taking it from that. However, I want points to be stored cumulatively, not overwrited.

I've changed the JavaScript on the page and the PHP works when a correct SQL statement is used.

```
<?php

include('Link.php');


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `Employees` SET `carbo_points` = 400 WHERE 
`Employees`.`employee_id` = 1; ");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['CarboPoints']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();


echo "Carbo Points have been stored.";

?>
```

This will change the Carbo Points of the user with employee id 1 to 400 in the database. However, I want a working SQL statement where the user adds the 'CarboPoints' they earned from that specific journey to their current total. But I do not know how to include the 'CarboPoints' variable I have created in ajax within the SQL statement.

Comment: You don't have any bindings in your query

Comment: How would I do that then?

Comment: Change `400` to `?`, and you would probably have to bind employee_id the same way

Comment: Thanks a lot, the only problem is that the SQL statement overwrites it, so 400 would change to 2, not 402, how would I add them together, I think I have to use the SUM statement right?

Answer (score 1):

It seems do you have several questions:

1.- **Add instead overwrite** You can change sql to add points: `SET carbo_points = carbo_points + new_points`.

2.- **Get points from ajax parameters** Just use `?` to [parametrize](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) query: `carbo_points = carbo_points + ?` .

In summary:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `Employees` 
                          SET `carbo_points` = `carbo_points` + ? 
                          WHERE `Employees`.`employee_id` = 1; ");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['CarboPoints']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Now that I realise what I asked, I did ask two questions, one relating to the adding of points not overwriting, and setting the '?' as a parameter, thanks for that, I'll give it a go now and see how I get on.